# IntelliJ always restarting/closing Spring root on class reload

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using Spring and Tomcat, it worked before fine but now, on each add that should be hot swappable it just restarts the server.

Something easy just as adding System.out.println("Something") into a method, if I press update classes and resources, it says 1 class reloaded and starts to restart the server for some reason. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you're deploying `:exploded` artifacts?

Comment: yes, its :war exploded that is being deployed